# Drupal Commons: notify all users on creation of new group

Tags: 7

In Drupal Commons (D7) I'd like to have all users notified by email when a new group is created.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rules module and set it to fire an action, when a group is created.

[CVS Instructions](http://drupal.org/node/97183/cvs-instructions/HEAD)
You could also implement this [User register notify](http://drupal.org/project/user_register_notify)

But since Drupal Commons uses Organic Groups
you might be able to use this [Organic Groups Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/og_notifications)
but take a look at the Rules module and Flag module.

best regards